# if statement error!

Tags: c++, if-statement

I got the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'max(int&, int&, int&, int&)'

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int g1l= rand()%5;
    int g1r= rand()%5;
    int g2l= rand()%5;
    int g2r= rand()%5;
    int g3l= rand()%5;
    int g3r= rand()%5;
    int g4l= rand()%5;
    int g4r= rand()%5;
    int g5l= rand()%5;
    int g5r= rand()%5;
    int g6l= rand()%5;
    int g6r= rand()%5;
    int manudw = 0;
    int manudd = 0;
    int manudl = 0;
    int lagalw = 0;
    int lagald = 0;
    int lagall = 0;
    int rmadw = 0;
    int rmadd = 0;
    int rmadl = 0;
    int acmilw = 0;
    int acmild = 0;
    int acmill = 0;

    int manudp = ((manudw*3)+(manudd*1));
    int lagalp = ((lagalw*3)+(lagald*1));
    int rmadp = ((rmadw*3)+(rmadd*1));
    int acmilp = ((acmilw*3)+(acmild*1));
    string manud = "Manchester United";
    string lagal = "Los Angeles Galaxy";
    string rmad = "Real Madrid";
    string acmil = "AC Milan";
    string place1 = "Manchester United  |";
    string place2 = "Real Madrid        |";
    string place3 = "AC Milan           |";
    string place4 = "Los Angeles Galaxy |";
    int counter=0;
    int round1;
    int round2;
    int round3;
    int manudgd = 0;
    int rmadgd = 0;
    int acmilgd = 0;
    int lagalgd = 0;
    do
    {
        int manudp = ((manudw*3)+(manudd*1));
        int lagalp = ((lagalw*3)+(lagald*1));
        int rmadp = ((rmadw*3)+(rmadd*1));
        int acmilp = ((acmilw*3)+(acmild*1));
        int manudgd = ((g1l+g3r+g6r)-(g1r+g3l+g6l));
        int rmadgd = ((g2l+g3l+g5r)-(g2r+g3r+g5l));
        int acmilgd = ((g2r+g4l+g6l)-(g2l+g4r+g6r));
        int lagalgd = ((g1r+g4r+g5l)-(g1l+g4l+g5r));
        cout<<place1<<" "<<manudw<<" | "<<manudd<<" | "<<manudl<<" | "<<manudp<<" | "<<manudgd<<"  |"<<endl<<
              place2<<" "<<rmadw<<" | "<<rmadd<<" | "<<rmadl<<" | "<<rmadp<<" | "<<rmadgd<<"  |"<<endl<<
              place3<<" "<<acmilw<<" | "<<acmild<<" | "<<acmill<<" | "<<acmilp<<" | "<<acmilgd<<"  |"<<endl<<
              place4<<" "<<lagalw<<" | "<<lagald<<" | "<<lagall<<" | "<<lagalp<<" | "<<lagalgd<<"  |"<<endl<<endl;
//        if(max(manudgd,rmadgd,lagalgd,acmilgd)==manudgd || max(manudgd,rmadgd,lagalgd,acmilgd)==rmadgd || max(manudgd,rmadgd,lagalgd,acmilgd)==lagalgd || max(manudgd,rmadgd,lagalgd,acmilgd)==acmilgd)
        if(counter==0)
        {
            for(round1=0;round1<=0;round1++)
            {
                cout<<"Manchester United "<<g1l<<"-"<<g1r<<" Los Angeles Galaxy"<<endl;
                cout<<"Real Madrid "<<g2l<<"-"<<g2r<<" AC Milan"<<endl<<endl;
                int manudgd = ((g1l)-(g1r));
                int rmadgd = ((g2l)-(g2r));
                int acmilgd = ((g2r)-(g2l));
                int lagalgd = ((g1r)-(g1l));
                if(g1l>g1r)
                {
                    manudw++;
                    lagall++;
                }
                else if(g1l<g1r)
                {
                    lagalw++;
                    manudl++;
                }
                else if(g1l==g1r)
                {
                    manudd++;
                    lagald++;
                }
                if(g2l>g2r)
                {
                    rmadw++;
                    acmill++;
                }
                else if(g2l<g2r)
                {
                    rmadl++;
                    acmilw++;
                }
                else if(g2l==g2r)
                {
                    rmadd++;
                    acmild++;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(counter==1)
        {
            for(round2=0;round2<=0;round2++)
            {
                cout<<"Real Madrid "<<g3l<<"-"<<g3r<<" Manchester United"<<endl;
                cout<<"AC Milan "<<g4l<<"-"<<g4r<<" Los Angeles Galaxy"<<endl<<endl;
                int manudgd = ((g1l+g3r)-(g1r+g3l));
                int rmadgd = ((g2l+g3l)-(g2r+g3r));
                int acmilgd = ((g2r+g4l)-(g2l+g4r));
                int lagalgd = ((g1r+g4r)-(g1l+g4l));
                if(g3l>g3r)
                {
                    rmadw++;
                    manudl++;
                }
                else if(g3l<g3r)
                {
                    manudw++;
                    rmadl++;
                }
                else if(g3l==g3r)
                {
                    manudd++;
                    rmadd++;
                }
                if(g4l>g4r)
                {
                    acmilw++;
                    lagall++;
                }
                else if(g4l<g4r)
                {
                    acmill++;
                    lagalw++;
                }
                else if(g4l==g4r)
                {
                    lagald++;
                    acmild++;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(counter==2)
        {
            for(round3=0;round3<=0;round3++)
            {
                cout<<"Los Angeles Galaxy "<<g5l<<"-"<<g5r<<" Real Madrid"<<endl;
                cout<<"AC Milan "<<g6l<<"-"<<g6r<<" Manchester United"<<endl<<endl;
                int manudgd = ((g1l+g3r+g6r)-(g1r+g3l+g6l));
                int rmadgd = ((g2l+g3l+g5r)-(g2r+g3r+g5l));
                int acmilgd = ((g2r+g4l+g6l)-(g2l+g4r+g6r));
                int lagalgd = ((g1r+g4r+g5l)-(g1l+g4l+g5r));
                if(g5l>g5r)
                {
                    lagalw++;
                    rmadl++;
                }
                else if(g5l<g5r)
                {
                    rmadw++;
                    lagall++;
                }
                else if(g5l==g5r)
                {
                    lagald++;
                    rmadd++;
                }
                if(g6l>g6r)
                {
                    acmilw++;
                    manudl++;
                }
                else if(g6l<g6r)
                {
                    acmill++;
                    manudw++;
                }
                else if(g6l==g6r)
                {
                    manudd++;
                    acmild++;
                }
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
    while(counter!=4);
}
```

The line I got the error on was on the 74th line:

```
if(max(manudgd,rmadgd,lagalgd,acmilgd)==manudgd || max(manudgd,rmadgd,lagalgd,acmilgd)==rmadgd || max(manudgd,rmadgd,lagalgd,acmilgd)==lagalgd || max(manudgd,rmadgd,lagalgd,acmilgd)==acmilgd)
```

This was all in C++ just in case you don't see the tags or recognize the code.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where are you expecting the max function to come from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Bob. It's nice that you read how to embed code in a question; thanks for that. It's not so nice is that you embedded **lots** of code in your question. Try to present a minimal example next time around. And once again, welcome aboard.

Comment: It's good that you've pasted a block of code that's complete enough to reproduce your error, but it would have been better if you could have cut it down so it was a minimal block of code that gives the same error.

Comment: Sweet merciful Gods, my poor useless eyes!

Comment: Time to pick up a C++ beginners book and read it thoroughly. I recommend Herbert Schildt "Complete Reference" (though there might be better books, that others can recommend. I can only recommend what I know).

Comment: `stdlib.h` and friends are deprecated in C++. Use `cstdlib` and friends, and throw away whatever useless book you're using. Get [a real one](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources). Also, whilst I'm here..... jesus christ....

Answer (score 6):

`max` gets just two arguments, so you have to composite it from multiple calls.

```
int maxGd = max(max(manudgd,rmadgd),max(lagalgd,acmilgd));
if(maxGd == manudgd || maxGd == lagalgd || maxGd == acmilDg) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::max` takes two arguments, not an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please use the [SO Markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting code in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

`max` takes two arguments. You may want to see [max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/). By the way, your code may need some refactoring - please read [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) from Robert C. Martin.

Comment: No, I think he needs to read something more *basic* first: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642

Comment: @Martinho: I think general coding style and C++ (or any language)-specific knowledge is largely orthogonal, and so can be learnt in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is no `max` function that takes four arguments. `max` takes only two arguments. You can write one such function yourself, using the one that already exists:

```
int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return max(max(a,b),max(c,d));
}
```

Comment: Without a `return`, I'm not sure this does what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ [**`std::max()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) takes only two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Eh? There is no `max()` function that I am aware of which takes four arguments! There is a two arg version, `std::max()` in `<algorithm>`.

If this is your own, implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no such function called `max` that takes 4 arguments in the c++ and you haven't defined one!

Comment: oh, I thought I saw the max function before in c++ =/

Comment: well there is one, as other have already pointed out, but it takes only 2 arguments not 4. You can implement your own or use the std one as shown by @marc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in the code where you've implemented `max(int&, int&, int&, int&)` method.

In C++ `<algorithm>` library, you can find [`std::max()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) declared as follows:

```
template <class T> const T& max ( const T& a, const T& b );
template <class T, class Compare>
  const T& max ( const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp );
```

Answer (score 0):

The max() function has not been defined in the scope of the call.
Add a definition and compile again.

Side note: max() is a macro in some compilers, but then with 2 arguments instead of 4.